# Symfony translation locale in Url losing after Login

Tags: url, twig, translation, symfony-2.8

I have define 2 Buttons in the Base.html.twig witch are switching the locale in the Url and change the text on the page in an other language:

```
<a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}"> 

<a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'de'})) }}">
```

The buttons change the Url like:

```
    http://localhost/en/login
    to
    http://localhost/de/login
```

It’s works good. But after the login, the locale will be set back to the default **en** set in the config.yml

Example:

- Open the website and see the login form
- Change the language from default **en** to **de** with the button
- Type in the login values and click „Login“
- The Startpage will be shown, but the locale in the Url is change back
  to the default **en** and **de** is loosing
- If I now change the lcale again to **de** it will keep it and work also by opening other pages

So the question is how do i keep the locale in the Url from befor login to the startpage after login ?

Thx

### **Setup infos:**

- Apache 2.4
- Symfony 2.8
- Using JMSI18nRoutingBundle

security.yml:

```
- access_control:
      { path: ^/[a-z][a-z]/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      { path: ^/[a-z][a-z]/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }        
      { path: ^/[a-z][a-z]/ap, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

 - main:
       anonymous: ~
       form_login:
       login_path: login
       check_path: login
```

config.yml:

```
 - parameters:
       locale: en

 - jms_i18n_routing:
       default_locale: en
       locales: [en, de]
       strategy: prefix

 - framework:
       #esi: ~
       translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
```

The Login-Form:

```
<form class="form_login" action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post" nmae="form_login">

        <input class="tf_login" type="text" id="username" name="_username" placeholder="{% trans %}login_us_name{% endtrans %}" value="{{ last_username }}" />

        <input class="tf_login" type="password" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="{% trans %}login_pass{% endtrans %}" />

        <input class="btn_login" type="submit" value="{% trans %}login_btn{% endtrans %}" />
    </form>
```

Comment: can you show how do you do the login ?
Maybe you redirect after the login on the default page (without the local) ?

Comment: Okay, I added the Login-Form

Answer (score 0):

You form action is 'login', so by default, you login is in english.

You can follow [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html) and it should work

Comment: Thx, but the action="{{ path('login') }}" generate the corret Path with the locale I set. 

I have print it out and the locale is inside the path, so if I change the language with a button to 'de' the {{ path('login') }} is: /de/login and if I click the englisch button the {{ path('login') }} is: /en/login, so this should be work. 
After the login the locale is sticky and works very well...

Comment: So what is the problem ? you said "But after the login, the locale will be set back to the default en" in your post

Comment: Yes I mean that when I change the language after I ve been logged in, it works and is sticky. It only losing it between the login-page and the first page after login.

Comment: this is what i said, read the doc i send. you have to set the local on the login then it will redirect on the right page